# Issue with setting Authorization header using Express JS implemenitng Using Cognito User Pool Authentication

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am implementing authentication using Cognito User Pool. I am only using NodeJS + Express JS, so whole coding is on server side and client side I just render html file using templates.

I am using below code to autheticate the user passing username and password.

```
  const cognitoProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
    cognitoProvider.adminInitiateAuth(params, function (err, result) {})
```

If authentication is sucessfull, result object has the accesstoken, tokentype and refresh token. Now I am not clear on how to set Authorzation header with this result which has the token. After this code I redirect user to the home page where I welcome the user. In subsequent request I want to retrieve token from header to check if user has logged in. But issue is I am not able to set the authorization header.

Below is the code:

```
 cognitoProvider.adminInitiateAuth(params, function (err, result) {
       
    If (err == null)
    {
    res.set('Authorization', result.AuthenticationResult); // Is this correct ? Even If i use this in next request I cannot retrieve Authorization header using req.header['Authorization']. I am not sure if I am coding this correctly.
    //Below is my next line of code
    res.redirect('/home'); // I redirect user to home page. I am not using render here as I was to avoid the post back message in case user tries to refresh the page, so I use redirect. 
    }
    })
```

I have spend hours but not able to make this work. May be I am missing some basic concept here.  Code Below of /users where I pass username & Password:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = "REGION COMES HERE";

const cognitoProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

  const username = req.body['InputEmail'];
  const password = req.body['InputPassword'];

  const params = {

    "AuthFlow": "ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "AuthParameters": {
      "USERNAME": username,
      "PASSWORD": password
    },
    "UserPoolId": "USERPOOLID",
    "ClientId": "CLIENTID"
  }
  cognitoProvider.adminInitiateAuth(params, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      var errormessage;
      switch (err.code) {
        case 'NotAuthorizedException':
          errormessage = err.message
          break;
        default:
          errormessage = "Issues encountered. Try Again";
      }
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express', message: errormessage });
      return;
    }
    if (result.ChallengeName) {
      switch (result.ChallengeName) {
        case 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED':
          res.render('firsttimelogin', { title: 'Express', username:username, message: '' });
          break;
        default:
          res.render('index', { title: 'Express', message: '' });
      }
    } else {
      res.set('Authorization', result.AuthenticationResult);
      res.redirect('/home');         
    }
});
});
module.exports = router;
```

---

Code of /Home

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
var token = req.header['Authorization'];
  if (token) {
    res.render('home', { title: 'Express'});
  }
  else{
    res.redirect('/');  
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: could you format and add the code segments please ?

Comment: code is added in main question